# IIS is not releasing the Memory

Tags: asp.net, iis, testing

I am running a load testing using HP Load Runner where I connect 200 users for one hour to IIS. 
the task manager shows the memory keeps increasing. after the load testing finishes. the memory is not releasing even after i waited a day.

If I try to run 250 virtual users, i got errors  till the number drops by itself to 198 virtual  users.[image]

and of course, IISreset make things back to normal

Comment: The website must be allocating that amount of memory during its processing and not releasing it until the app pool restarts. E.g. `Application.Cache[<--- 452MB of data]`. Perhaps you could load up a profiler on your application to determine where the memory consumption is occurring. redgate Ants Profiler is pretty good.

Comment: Do u mean it is the cache. we use caching  a lot.I have Ants Profiler, what should I look for??

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to start the profilier then walk through some pages (whatever you load tester is doing), then stop the profiler.  They have all kinds of graphs and timelines of various resources you can view. 450 MB of memory wouldn't be uncommon for 250 concurrent users, but the information (if it's in session or some other store that expires) should free up after an amount of time if it is being inserted correctly.

This would be a good opportunity to walk through the results of the profiler and determine where your memory efficiencies could be gained (e.g. using a thread safe shared instance rather than a per user instance, etc).